# What is the ExtendedImage property for in TListViews TListGroup?

Tags: listview, delphi

If I specify any number like this:

```
Tasks.Groups.Items[1].ExtendedImage := 0;
```

then group header just disappears.

I think I've searched everywhere and couldn't find anything helpful

Comment: You have to assign a (filled) ImageList to the GroupHeaderImages in your TListView. And, according to the documentation, ExtendedImages are available only in Vista/Win7... Did you check this?

Comment: Yes. Everything.
I've tested it under vista and currently trying to do something under Windows 7.
Also I've tried different ImageList sizes

Comment: ExtendedImage has been deleted from the documentation; seems odd

Comment: I found only this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/ComCtrls.TListGroup.ExtendedImage not very usefull, indeed...

Comment: The `ExtendedImge` property uses the `LVGF_EXTENDEDIMAGE` flag when calling `ListView_InsertGroup()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775034.aspx).